# How to disable doubleclick ActionButton in ActionGroups in Kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Iwant to have a drop-down menu in my ActionBar. 
An actiongroup in a spinner mode does what I want to have. 
The only problem with this solution is that ActionButtons need to be double-clicked (or longer-clicked) inside the Actiongroup, while outside of it they could be single-clicked. I would like to use singleclicks.
Could anyone help me with this?

Using: Python 3.4 ; Kivy 1.8.0; Win 7

```
    #menu-line on the top
ActionBar:
    size_hint: 1, None
    ActionView:
        use_separator: True
        ActionPrevious:
            title: 'title'
            with_previous: False
            disabled: True
        ActionButton:
            text: 'button'
        ActionGroup:
            mode: 'spinner'
            text: 'Languages'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'German'
                on_press: root.do_something()
            ActionButton:
                text: 'English'
                on_release: root.do_something()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**warning:** The answer isn't pretty.

If you follow [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/1906) issue, you'll see that the problem is that `ActionButton`s event's aren't mapped. The solution involves giving the `ActionGroup` an id so that it can be referenced, changing the mode to `spinner`(which you've already done), and connecting the `ActionGroup._dropdown`s `select` event to your callback:

```
#menu-line on the top
ActionBar:
    size_hint: 1, None
    ActionView:
        use_separator: True
        ActionPrevious:
            title: 'title'
            with_previous: False
            disabled: True
        ActionButton:
            text: 'button'
        ActionGroup:
            id: action_group
            mode: 'spinner'
            text: 'Languages'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'German'
                on_release: action_group._dropdown.select(root.do_something())
            ActionButton:
                text: 'English'
                on_release: action_group._dropdown.select(root.do_something())
```